# Angular Material Forms and Flex Layout - getting equal input width across all rows

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

just stuck with a little FlexLayout formatting problem with my Angular Material Form.

My first name and last name inputs should cover the whole row end to end, such that the left end of the last name input and right end of the first name input are perpendicular to the respective end of the email input.

How can i get this to work? Basically I just want them to have a matching width with the other form inputs.

Instead of a matching 'row wrap' width, they are really small
[image: Instead of a matching 'row wrap' width, they are really small]

Here is how it looks on mobile, again, first and last name are too small
[image: Here is how it looks on mobile, again, first and last name are too small]

I am using FlexLayout and the Angular Material component library to achieve all this. I am just not familiar with how to set up a useful subsection of a flexbox in a functioning way.

Here is the relevant code, no significant styling or layout functionality is applied outside of this component.html file.

```
<mat-card fxLayoutAlign="center center">
    <div *ngIf="isLoading">
        <app-loading-spinner></app-loading-spinner>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!isLoading">
        <form [formGroup]="contactForm" fxLayout="row wrap" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()">
            <div fxLayout="row" fxLayout.lt-sm="column" fxLayoutGap="16px">
                <mat-form-field fxFlexFill color="accent">
                    <input id="fName" matInput type="text" placeholder="Your first name" formControlName="firstName">
                </mat-form-field>
                <mat-form-field fxFlexFill color="accent">
                    <input id="lName" matInput type="text" placeholder="Your last name" formControlName="lastName">
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>

            <mat-form-field fxFlexFill color="accent">
                <input id="email" matInput type="text" placeholder="Your email" formControlName="email">
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-form-field fxFlexFill color="accent">
                <textarea
                    matInput
                    [rows]="6"
                    placeholder="Your message"
                    formControlName="message"></textarea>
            </mat-form-field>

            <button fxFlexFill color="accent" mat-raised-button type="submit" [disabled]="!contactForm.valid">Let's vacation!</button>
        </form>
    </div>

</mat-card>
```

If anyone has insight on how I can get this to work, that'd be so great!

Thank you in advance! This is my first post so I am open to some feedback on how I can improve my question asking.

Answer (score 5):

Easy solution, I just needed to sleep on it I guess.

```
    <div fxLayout="row" fxFlexFill fxLayout.lt-sm="column" fxLayoutGap="16px">
        <mat-form-field fxFlex color="accent">
            <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Your first name" formControlName="firstName">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field fxFlex color="accent">
            <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Your last name" formControlName="lastName">
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

All i had to do was add the fxFlexFill property to the row.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was searching for on Google.